# How do I get this terminal command to be executed from python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to run an executable for which input parameters are saved in a text file, say input.txt. The output is then redirected to a text file, say output.txt. In windows terminal, I use the command,

```
executable.exe < input.txt > output.txt
```

How can I do this from within a python program?

I understand that this can be achieved using os.system. But I wanted to run the same using subprocess module. I was trying something like this,

```
input_path = '<'+input+'>'
temp = subprocess.call([exe_path, input_path, 'out.out'])
```

But, the python code executes the exe file without directing the text file to it.

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/9521723

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To redirect input/output, use the `stdin` and `stdout` parameters of `call`:

```
with open(input_path, "r") as input_fd, open("out.out", "w") as output_fd:
    temp = subprocess.call([exe_path], stdin=input_fd, stdout=output_fd)
```